# Confirmation that I've interpreted theorem involving Dedekind cuts correctly

Tags: analysis

This theorem below is from the section on Dedekind cuts in "Princples of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin.

> Let $\alpha$ be a cut, and let $r>0$ be a given rational.  Then there are rationals $p$, $q$ such that  $p\in\alpha$, $q\notin\alpha$, $q$ is not that smallest upper number of $\alpha$ and $q-p=r$.

Firstly, I would like to know if I am correct in interpreting this theorem as basically saying that we can express any positive rational as the difference of two rationals where one is in a cut while the other isn't?  Secondly, I also believe that the restriction that $q$ not be the smallest upper number is necessary because it allows us the freedom to choose very large values of $q$ in the event that $r$ is also large.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What edition are you using? I am looking at Edition 3 and can't find the theorem.

Comment: Doesn't explicitly say which edition it is, but I'm pretty sure it's the first edition.  It's theorem 1.15; it follows the proof of the commutative and associative laws for cuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you're correct in the basic interpretation, but here's how I would phrase it: Given any rational distance, there are rational points on either side of the cut which are exactly that close together. The reason I'd phrase it in terms of "closeness" is because, usually, when a theorem talks about "any positive rational" or "any positive real", it's really talking about "any positive rational *no matter how small*" - the idea is that big numbers aren't as interesting or difficult to satisfy as small numbers.

As for the part about $q$ not being the smallest upper number of $\alpha$: this isn't *necessary*, it's just *useful*. The theorem would still be true if you dropped that condition, because the condition is part of the conclusion. It means that the statement about "closeness" isn't just talking about the bottom half of the cut, it's talking about both halves. If we allowed $q$ to be that smallest upper number, then all the theorem would be saying is that the bottom half of the cut "squeezes close" to $q$; in principle, the upper half could be very spread out.

But the best way to get a feel for a theorem is to look at how it's used. I think you'll find that the theorem is used more for small values of $r$ than for large; it will also probably be useful that $p$ and $q$ are strictly on different sides of the cut (with neither of them falling exactly in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of cuts, I can only tell you my intuitive feel for the theorem. Rudin is saying that for any given cut, we can 'squeeze into' it from both the left and right with rational numbers. You never want the rational numbers to be 'equal' to the cut, since he is saying that you can approximate the cut from either the left or right with rational numbers. So $r$ is like $\varepsilon$ - it is only 'interesting' for small 'challenging' numbers.

Also, in general cuts do not have a smallest upper number, so I am not sure where you are going with the 'secondly' part of your question.

Read ahead to see how this theorem is used. I would bet you are analyzing a fixed cut, and then since you can take $r$ to be arbitrarily small, that ______ is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a fair amount of time on this theorem on my first go around of Rudin's book. Yes, it shows up in the 1st and 2nd edition of his book but not the 3rd. It is not intuitive...

Theorem 1.15 states that for any rational $p$ defined within the cut, there exists a corresponding rational $q$ not within the cut such that the distance between the two is $r$, and $q$ is not the smallest upper number.

Well, what does this mean?

What this means is there will always exist some rational $p$ and $q$ such that their relationship is defined by $p+r=q$, and where $q$ is not the smallest upper number of the cut. This is a proof about EXISTENCE, nothing more. And I think that is the part that is difficult to see.

The way he goes about proving it is he creates a sequence of numbers $s_n$ for all integers $0,1,2,...$ and says that if $s_m$ is within the cut and $s_{m+1}$ is not within the cut, and $s_{m+1}$ is NOT the smallest upper number, then we are done. If it is the smallest upper number, simply increase $s_{m}$ and $s_{m+1}$ by $\frac{r}{2}$ (this is clear since if $s_{m+1}$ is indeed the smallest upper number, then we can do this by how we defined $p+r=q$.)

That's all this theorem and proof is. It's proof of existence.

It is easy to overthink this theorem because of the "smallest upper number" component. But this is an important aspect of proving Theorem 1.16.